# Add a JScrollBar to a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, scrollable, jscrollbar

I am trying to make a GUI server-to-client message program.  I wrote the network side, and that is irrelevant to the problem.  I am trying to make a JTextArea scroll with a JScrollBar.  How would I do this?  Here is my code for the client (with most of the networking code removed):

```
public class MyClient extends JFrame
{

    public Client client;
    public static Scanner scanner;      
    public JTextField textField;
    public JLabel label;        
    public static String string;        
    public static JTextArea textArea;           
    public String username;                 
    public JScrollBar scrollBar;        
    public JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public MyClient()
    {                   
        setTitle("Client");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());                    
        textArea = new JTextArea("");           
        scrollBar = new JScrollBar();           
        label = new JLabel("Please enter your message");
        add(label);         
        textField = new JTextField(70);
        add(textField);
        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {               
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {                   
                textArea.append(username + ": " + textField.getText() + "\n");                  textField.setText(null);                    
            }               
        }); 

        add(textArea);          
        add(scrollBar, BorderLayout.EAST);          
        string = textField.getText();                       
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);           
    }

     class MyAdjustmentListener implements AdjustmentListener 
     {

            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) 
            {                   
               label.setText("    New Value is " + e.getValue() + "      ");
               repaint();                  
            }               
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {           
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {                   
                MyClient myClient = new MyClient();
                myClient.setVisible(true);
                myClient.setResizable(false);                   
            }

        });         
    }       
}
```

Comment: You don't add a `JScrollBar` to a `JTextArea`. You add a `JTextArea` to a `JScrollPane`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a `JScrollPane` instead of a `JScrollBar`, try this code:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea ("");

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (textArea, 
   JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

In the above code, you are assigning a `textArea` to a `ScrollPane` and making it scroll `vertically` and `horizontally`.

Another way of doing it, Create the ScrollPane containing the TextArea and then Setting vertical scroll = always on  :

```
JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea();     
JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane(textArea); 

scroll. setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane. VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
```

Read here for tutorial: [Tutorial Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the `JTextArea` inside the `JScrollPane` and then add the `JScrollPane` in the container instead of adding `JTextArea` itself.

There is no need of adding `JScrollBar`, scroll bars are by default shown if needed.

Sample code:

```
textArea = new JTextArea("");
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

Find a working sample here [How can we add JScrollPane on JTextArea in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212126/how-can-we-add-jscrollpane-on-jtextarea-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top)

---

Some of the points that I noticed in your code:

1. `JFrame` default layout is changed to `FlowLayout`

   ```
   setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   ```
2. Now adding components as per the `BorderLayout` properties

   ```
   add(scrollBar, BorderLayout.EAST);
   ```
3. A lots of instance variables are declared but never used in the code.

**Note:** First add the components in a container such as `JPanel` then finally add the `JPanel` in the `JFrame`.

Please read it again [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and choose the appropriate layout manager for your application design.

Comment: Now I have this  :textArea= new JTextArea();  
  
  scrollPane= new JScrollPane(textArea);
  add(scrollPane);                                          It still isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried with the sample code that I shared in the link? Try first with the simple code.